# CSS Background image cut off by li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code will load a background image that is cut off or covered by the ul/li's

This only occurs with bootstrap. I have it on jsfiddle
without bootstrap:https://jsfiddle.net/kng2upm1/
with bootstrap:https://jsfiddle.net/kng2upm1/1/

**HTML**

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt"Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a href="">Git Hub</a>
            <li> <a href="">Game Vote Alpha</a>
            <li> <a href="">Minecraft Server</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<h1>File Directories</h1>
<ul id="filelist">
    <li> <a href="">TV Shows</a>
    <li> <a href="">Movies</a>
    <li> <a href="">Music</a>
    <li> <a href="">Audio Books</a>
    <li> <a href="">Games</a>
    <li> <a href="">Pen and Paper RPG Scans</a>
</ul>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#filelist{
    list-style-type: none;
}

html{
  background-image: url("image");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 500px auto;
  background-attatchment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: do you want the picture to be the background of the list?

Comment: What are you looking for, a way to keep the text on the left, and way to move the picture down, something else?

Comment: I want the background image to stay on the right side of the screen and have any other content go over it the way that <body background="image"> does but with only the one image, not tiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap adds a `background-color: #fff` to the body, since you are applying the image to the HTML element, try changing your css to put the image on the body element.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgd2d99h/

Answer (score 0):

Add background to body tag (inline css)

```
<body background="http://67.media.tumblr.com/9c2cc013377eef3aa10cf4859c38349f/tumblr_nlbiqoxbtv1qlhoglo1_500.png">
```

Bootstrap might be overriding your background...

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap containers were all messed up. You had the background just in one of the nested elements. You should put your background element into the largest containing parent element for the best effect.

HTML:

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li> <a href="https://github.com/damphon">Git Hub</a>
            <li> <a href="http://gn.jeremytoler.net">Game Vote Alpha</a>
            <li> <a href="http://mc.jeremytoler.net">Minecraft Server</a>
        </ul>



<h1>File Directories</h1>
<ul id="filelist">
    <li> <a href="/TV">TV Shows</a>
    <li> <a href="/Movies">Movies</a>
    <li> <a href="/Music">Music</a>
    <li> <a href="/AudioBooks">Audio Books</a>
    <li> <a href="/Games">Games</a>
    <li> <a href="/RPG">Pen and Paper RPG Scans</a>
    <li> <a href="/EduVid">Programing Videos</a>
</ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#filelist{
    list-style-type: none;
}

html{

}

.container-fluid{
      background-image: url("http://67.media.tumblr.com/9c2cc013377eef3aa10cf4859c38349f/tumblr_nlbiqoxbtv1qlhoglo1_500.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attatchment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something Bootstrap is adding to your `body` tag. You can override it by using:

```
body{
  background-color: initial;
}
```

Make sure your CSS file is referenced **after** Bootstrap's.

---

```css
html {
  background-image: url("http://67.media.tumblr.com/9c2cc013377eef3aa10cf4859c38349f/tumblr_nlbiqoxbtv1qlhoglo1_500.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 500px auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: right;
}
body {
  background-color: initial !important;
  /* !important to force Code Snippet to use this value.*/
}
#filelist {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li> <a href="https://github.com/damphon">Git Hub</a>
            <li> <a href="http://gn.jeremytoler.net">Game Vote Alpha</a>
              <li> <a href="http://mc.jeremytoler.net">Minecraft Server</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1>File Directories</h1>
  <ul id="filelist">
    <li> <a href="/TV">TV Shows</a>
      <li> <a href="/Movies">Movies</a>
        <li> <a href="/Music">Music</a>
          <li> <a href="/AudioBooks">Audio Books</a>
            <li> <a href="/Games">Games</a>
              <li> <a href="/RPG">Pen and Paper RPG Scans</a>
                <li> <a href="/EduVid">Programing Videos</a>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't style the `HTML` tag...

....style the `body` tag.

The HTML tag should *never* be styled for visual changes.

Merely changing your CSS to apply to the **body** tag rather than the HTML tag corrects this issue.

[Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/kng2upm1/3/)

(there are also markup errors in your html)